# How can I create post templates that users can choose from?

Tags: custom-post-types

I have created a user driven site for the Talmud. I have made a couple posts and would like other users posts to look the same. I'm not talking about the actually page, just the post content. I would like to create templates that the users can choose from that look exactly my post and they can then just insert their own text their. Is this possible? And if its is how would I do it.

Comment: To some extent it should be possible. You probably want a combination of custom meta and content, but without more detail it is going to be difficult to give specifics.

Comment: I always thought [*post formats*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) where suitable for this kind of setup, but I don't think you can add your own custom post format. I must admit I never fully understood the idea behind these hardcoded formats ;-) So try what @s_ha_dum suggested.

Comment: @birgire : I agree. The decision to lock post formats to the Core defaults is one of the worst in WordPress development history... but maybe that is just me.

Comment: @s_ha_dum that's true and I was happy that the  proposed "post format UI" core feature was dropped in the 3.6 release.

Comment: I will probably just make a video showing users how a post should be formatted. I just wish their was a way where they could select a format and it would appear in the text editor and then they could simply insert text where necessary

Answer (score 0):

I recently did the same using this tutorial: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/create-custom-single-post-templates-for-specific-posts-or-sections-in-wordpress

If you're looking for an easier option, there's also a plugin for creating post templates: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template

Hope this helps.